# Method not found: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1

Tags: c#, web-services

Hi I'm getting this follow error on my WebService when I publish it,

- Method not found:
  'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1
  System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter.get_SupportedMediaTypes()'.
  [image]

but when I'm  using it on VS debug mode it doesn't happen.
I already googled it and tried to use assembly reference on webconfig but it didn't work 
any sugestion ?

This is my  current webconfig file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3000000" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
       <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

and this is the class that is throwing the error

```
class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the web.config adding also the "assembly reference"? (I do not know what you mean by that)

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin I think OP is referring to a [binding redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117030/binding-redirect-for-system-net-http-doesnt-work-why). OP: you may want to add version numbers (visual studio, .net framework, dll version)

Comment: Hey! I just updated the web.config code the version  that  I'm  using is assembly System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not with `System.Net.Http.Formatting` but with `System.Net.Http`. Add the following assembly redirect:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

The newVersion may be different in your case. You can try `4.2.0.0` also.

Comment: hmmm  it didn't work  too, I removed this line and  it worked I'm not sure but it seems to  be happening only in my  local iis when I publish  it,  on the serve it worked properly thanks in advance

Comment: You should try to fix it in your local environment. This is the kind of issue you will experience again and it will be better if you know how to tackle it. Can you tell us the version of System.Net.Http? (Go to the web project > References, search for System.Net.Http > Properties)

Comment: Yeah that's true, the version is 4.2.0.0, I also check the nuget version and  it is installed at the lastest