# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm using **Asp.Net Web API** framework by developing API'S in visual studio 2019. Project is building and easily execute at my local machine and i can test the API's as well.
But when i publish the code on my shared server, and run the URL, http://foneme.dewy.com.pk/,
this is giving an error, states

> "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Hi, can you tell me the solution how i can resolve this issue.
(Thanks)

Comment: please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570912/strange-issue-with-system-net-http-4-2-0-0-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I got this after updating my ASP.NET project from .NET 4.7.1 to 4.7.2. I used half a day searching for a solution. Some suggested to change (or add) the binding redirect in Web.Config.

I solved it by REMOVING the binding instead, in all projects using this in the solution. The binding worked in .NET 4.7.1, but seemed to be giving errors after upgrading.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, i'm using already .Net 4.7.2, this is working at local but creating problem at live server

Comment: What kind of server? A VM or with accessible OS or a cloud SaaS?

Comment: This is shared windows hosting server, this is the link http://foneme.dewy.com.pk/

Comment: Are you referencing System.Net.Http from NuGet or from system reference? If NuGet, try to force reinstall all NuGets on all projects in solution from Packet Manager console by using Update-Package -reinstall, delete "obj" folder and rebuild your solution. Check for errors during this process.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response,i found the problem , actually the server does not support the .Net framework version that i was using for web API's project.
I change the .Net framework version, so now this is working. Thanks